# How to change startTime and endTime in FullCalendar 5.11

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar, vuejs3

Hi i use Fullcalendar and i want to change start time and end time i wrote this but didn't work. i see start time is 00 and end time is 23 i dont want to this.

how can i solved this problem.

```
    <script> 
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId } from './event-utils'
import trLocale from "@fullcalendar/core/locales/tr";
 
export default {
  

  components: {
    FullCalendar 
  },

  data: function() {
    return {
      
      calendarOptions: {
       
       locale:trLocale,
       firstDay:1,
       
       
       
       
        businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday,Friday
    startTime: '08:45', // 8am
    endTime: '18:00' // 6pm
  },
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 6 ], // Satuday
    startTime: '08:45', 
    endTime: '12:30' 
  }
],
```